# Extending swift optional for default values

Tags: swift

I'm trying to extend Swift's `Optional` type with default values. Providing empty values in API requests should raise an exception. I've done this for the `String` type, but I can't achieve the same result with the `Integer` type:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {

    var unwrappedValue: String {

        get {
            switch self {

            case .some(let value):
                return value

            case .none:
                return ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Integer` version is throwing the following `Error`:

> Protocol 'Integer' can only be used as a generic constraint because it
>   has Self or associated type requirements

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == Integer {

    var unwrappedValue: Integer {

        get {
            switch self {

            case .some(let value):
                return value

            case .none:
                return 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I would advise implementing such a computed property – just saying `someOptionalString ?? ""` is shorter and expresses your intention much more clearly.

Comment: Yes, that's also the way. I think it's about programming style and readability.

Comment: Optionals carry a semantic meaning. If they evaluate to nil it expresses "nothing", where nothing isn't equal to zero. By implementing default values you will loose this information.

Answer (score 6):

If you use this for a lot of Types you might want to consider the following addition to the answer of Leo Dabus:

```
protocol Defaultable {
    static var defaultValue: Self { get }
}

extension Optional where Wrapped: Defaultable {
    var unwrappedValue: Wrapped { return self ?? Wrapped.defaultValue }
}
```

This way you can extend your types very easily:

```
extension Int: Defaultable {
    static var defaultValue: Int { return 0 }
}

extension String: Defaultable {
    static var defaultValue: String { return "" }
}

extension Array: Defaultable {
    static var defaultValue: Array<Element> { return [] }
}
```

And usage goes like this:

```
let optionalInt: Int? = 10 // Optional(10)
let unwrappedInt = optionalInt.unwrappedValue // 10

let optionalString: String? = "Hello" // Optional("Hello")
let unwrappedString = optionalString.unwrappedValue // "Hello"

let optionalArray: [Int]? = nil // nil
let unwrappedArray = optionalArray.unwrappedValue // []
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to return Wrapped instead of Integer

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Integer {
    var unwrappedValue: Wrapped {
        switch self {
        case .some(let value):
            return value
        case .none:
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

or simply

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: Integer {
    var safelyUnwrapped: Wrapped { return self ?? 0 }
}
```

---

```
let optionalInt  = Int("10")
let unwrappedValue = optionalInt.safelyUnwrapped  // 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve using below code:

```
extension Optional {
   func defaultValue(_ val: Wrapped) -> Wrapped { return self ?? val }
}
var str: String?
str.defaultValue("User")

var a: Int?
a.defaultValue(2)
```

This will work for both data types.